# Install Gradle plugin for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to install Gradle Integration  for Eclipse but i get the following error:

```
Communication with repository at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle failed.
Communication with repository at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle failed.
Read timed out
```

Anyone knows if there is another way to install this plugin? I've Googled but only found links to install using Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the given URL reachable for you? (It is for me.) Anyway, another way to install the plugin is to follow the instructions on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle).

Comment: Yes, it is reachable for me. I will try the github way.

Answer (score 9):

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

works well with my eclipse3.7

Answer (score 5):

Use this link for Eclipse 4.4: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/
Use this link for Eclipse 4.3 or below: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7/
Make sure you only checked Gradle Integration package.

Hope that help for you!

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by turning off antivirus software.